# how to get session of username and update his username to the database whenever the user updates the gridview?

Tags: c#, session, gridview, webforms

I have this table called EntryTable. I displayed the data using gridview. But before that, the user need to login first in order to use that service. I hardcode the username as Admin. And after he login, and after he edit and once he clicked the update button, his name which is Admin will go to the MODIFIEDBY column field which is in the database.

don;t be confused by the name column, nothing to do with this. Only modifiedby column is important. Since I am login as Admin, my name is called admin. If i edit and updated the gridview, this name called admin will go to the modifiedby column in the database. Because admin modified it. If I update row one in gridview, the name admin will go in to modifiedby column field and not John Tan. If I update row two in gridview, the name admin will go in to modifiedby column field and not kevin wong. Always Admin because I am login as Admin. That means update modified column by the value of Session Name.

[image]

[image]

Login name is a label, id is called lblUsername.
[image]

**LOGIN.ASPX CODES**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtUserName.Text == "Admin" && txtPassword.Text == "123")
    {
        Session.Add("Username", txtUserName.Text);
        Session.Add("Password", txtPassword.Text);
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);
        Response.Redirect("BlogEntry.aspx");
    }

    else

        lblError.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password";
}
```

**AFTER LOGIN PAGE, UPDATEING AND PAGELOAD CODES.**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        bindResultGridView();

    }
    //Logout.Visible = false;
    string memName = (String)Session["UserName"];
    lblUsername.Text = String.Concat("Welcome Guest!");

    if (Session["Username"] != null && Session["Username"] != String.Empty)
    {
        lblUsername.Text = "Welcome, " + memName + "!";


    }

}


protected void grdBlog_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdBlog.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        bindResultGridView();
    }
    protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
        //  get product id from data key
        int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

    //  get current grid view row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
    //  find text box for txtPrice
    TextBox blogtype = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogType");
    TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox dateentry = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDateEntry");
    TextBox blogstory = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogStory");
    //  Remove $ sign
    string strName = name.Text;
    string strBlogType = blogtype.Text;
    string strDescription = description.Text;
    string strDateEntry = dateentry.Text;
    string strBlogStory = blogstory.Text;
    DateTime datDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateEntry, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
    {
        updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, datDate, strBlogStory);
    }

    else
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Invalid Date";
        lblSuccess.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void updateBlogGridviewRecord(int blogid, string strName, string strBlogType, string strDescription, DateTime datDate, string strBlogStory)
{
    try
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

        string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogType", strBlogType);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", datDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", strDescription);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogStory", strBlogStory);
        myConnect.Open();

        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            lblSuccess.Visible = true;
            lblSuccess.Text = "Record updated!";
            lblError.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSuccess.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "Update fail";
            lblError.Visible = false;
        }

        myConnect.Close();


        //Cancel Edit Mode
        grdBlog.EditIndex = -1;
        bindResultGridView();
    }

    catch
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Please Enter Approximate data";
        lblSuccess.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Following @puneet advice

```
 protected void grdBlog_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
    Session["Username"] = txtName.Text;

    int selectedRow = e.RowIndex;   //get selected row
    //  get product id from data key
    int blogid = (int)grdBlog.DataKeys[selectedRow].Value;

    //  get current grid view row
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grdBlog.Rows[selectedRow];
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
    //  find text box for txtPrice
    TextBox blogtype = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogType");
    TextBox description = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDescription");
    TextBox dateentry = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDateEntry");
    TextBox blogstory = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtBlogStory");
    //  Remove $ sign
    string strName = name.Text;
    string strBlogType = blogtype.Text;
    string strDescription = description.Text;
    string strDateEntry = dateentry.Text;
    string strBlogStory = blogstory.Text;
    DateTime datDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateEntry, new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" },
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
    {
        updateBlogGridviewRecord(blogid, strName, strBlogType, strDescription, datDate, strBlogStory);
    }

    else
    {
        lblError.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = "Invalid Date";
        lblSuccess.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is completely untested, but it seems to me like you could just do something along the lines of the following.

```
string strCommandText = "UPDATE EntryTable SET [ModifiedBy]=@Modifier, [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogID", blogid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", strName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogType", strBlogType);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateEntry", datDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", strDescription);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlogStory", strBlogStory);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modifier", Session["Username"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your grdBlog_RowUpdating method change Session value by the text input from user.

> `Session["Username"] = name.Text;`

Next time when page refreshes new name will appear.

Comment: What do u mean when page refresh, new name will appear. I added in codes above already. Is that correct? That Login Name is a label. so i put it as lblUsername.Text. So how do i write the query in the update? I wan to put in the session name into the modifiedby column field database after updating the gridview. @Puneet Khurana

Comment: I meant this
TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName"); 
Session["Username"] = name.Text;

Comment: I changed it to Session["Username"] = txtName.Text;  already. So what does it do? how to specified it to go to modifiedby column once update? @Puneet Khurana

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question. I guess you want to update modified column by the value of Name column. For this you need to update the ModifiedBy column before updating Name column. Change your update query as "UPDATE EntryTable SET [ModifiedBy] = [Name], [Name]=@Name, [BlogType]=@BlogType, [Description]=@Description, [DateEntry]=@DateEntry, [BlogStory]=@BlogStory WHERE [BlogID]=@BlogID"

Comment: Erm don;t be confused by the name column, nothing to do with this. Only modifiedby column is important. Since I am login as Admin, my name is called admin. If i edit and updated the gridview, this name called admin will go to the modifiedby column in the database. Because admin modified it. If I update row one in gridview, the name admin will go in to modifiedby column field and not John Tan. If I update row two in gridview, the name admin will go in to modifiedby column field and not kevin wong. Always Admin because I am login as Admin. Erm can understand? thanks haha @Puneet Khurana

Comment: update modified column by the value of Session Name. @Puneet Khurana